# Как лучше всего ожидать выполнения некоторого условия?

Tags: java

Предположим, что я ожидаю выполнения некоторого условия A, как тогда это лучше всего реализовать? У меня на уме 2 варианта, но не знаю, какой из них лучше.

```
while(!A);
```

или

```
while(!A)
   Thread.onSpinWait();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44622384/4928642

Comment: Очевидно, что второй лучше первого, но ещё лучше сделать по-нормальному через блокировки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лучше не использовать

```
while(!A);
```

т.к. в таком случае процессор не может распознать, что здесь подразумается ожидание и будет выполнять пустую операцию. Т.е. ты до выполнения своего условия возможно получишь 100% загрузки на одном ядре, что не лучший вариант.

Вариант

```
while(!A)
   Thread.onSpinWait();
```

немного лучше, но тоже плох, т.к. всё равно много пустых проверок.

Возможно вам стоит посмотреть в сторону триггерной модели. К примеру, с помощью [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html). В одном потоке вы создаёте этот [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html), далее передаёте его, но в виде [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) в другой поток, и запускаете этот другой поток. Грубо это может выглядеть вот так:

```
CompletableFuture<Object> future = new CompletableFuture<Object>();
new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        //....
        future.get(); //это вместо while
        //....
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}).start();
//.....
future.complete(new Object());
```

Answer (score 0):

Второй вариант.

> onSpinWait​ - Указывает, что вызывающий в данный момент не может прогрессировать, пока не произойдет одно или несколько действий со стороны других действий.